# Unwanted back-referencing in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I am getting page number of thesis after completion of each reference how do I remove it. I am using code for bib as follows

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
\bibliography{References/references} % References file
```

Example--

```
[1] Apache. Jena api, 2012. **7**
[2] Donald E. Knuth. Web Servies essentials. O’reilly, 2007. **7**
[3] J. Mogul H. Frystyk L. Masinter P.Leach T. Berners-Lee R.Fielding,
J.Gettys. Hypertext transfer protocol–http/1.1. http://www.w3.org /Pro-
tocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html, pages 57–76, 1999. **7**
```

Here page number 7 is problem

Comment: Hi Ratnesh, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for folks to play with? :)

Answer (score 5):

Without MWE, who know, but most probably is that you have `hyperref` package with that option:

```
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
```

To avoid this, change this option to false.

```
\usepackage[backref=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Or `\usepackage{backref}`